# SELECT DISTINCT is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

Let's say I have a table name TableA with the below partial data:

```
LOOKUP_VALUE     LOOKUPS_CODE     LOOKUPS_ID
------------     ------------     ----------
          5%              120           1001
          5%              121           1002
          5%              123           1003
          2%              130           2001
          2%              131           2002
```

I wanted to select only 1 row of 5% and 1 row of 2% as a view using DISTINCT but it fail, my query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lookup_value, lookups_code
  FROM TableA;
```

The above query give me the result as shown below.

```
LOOKUP_VALUE     LOOKUPS_CODE     
------------     ------------     
          5%              120           
          5%              121           
          5%              123           
          2%              130           
          2%              131
```

But that is not my expected result, mt expected result is shown below:

```
LOOKUP_VALUE     LOOKUPS_CODE     
------------     ------------     
          5%              120                                
          2%              130
```

May I know how can I achieve this without specifying any WHERE clause?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the table definition that you're selecting from?

Comment: Not possible without a `where` clause? Why don't you want to use one?

Comment: Your query should already fetch 1 row each of 5 and 2.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My TableA actually have around 500 rows of records and it is not possible for me to use a WHERE clause to include all the lookups_code. Furthermore, I just wanted to SELECT the lookup_value to be unique for my view and use in another query, that is why i think SELECT DISTINCT could work in this case

Comment: `I wanted to select only 1 row of 5% and 1 row of 2% as a view using DISTINCT`. Based on data provided, your query should work just fine.

Comment: Very strange, it works for me, see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c5890/1

Comment: Your query only returns a single column and **will** return each lookup_value only once. If that is not what you want, then please edit your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Hi all, sorry that I have miss out to SELECT a column in the query. I have edited my question with the expected result. Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT is not working` -- wrong

Comment: On what basis do you want the Lookups_code? Will any one do? If the Lookups_code is not important, why is it being selected?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're misunderstanding the scope of `DISTINCT`: it will give your distinct **rows**, not just distinct on the first field.

If you want one row for each distinct `LOOKUP_VALUE`, you either need a `WHERE` clause that will work out which one of them to show, or an aggregation strategy with a `GROUP BY` clause plus logic in the `SELECT` that tells the query how to aggregate the other columns (e.g. `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess at your problem - when you say

> "The above query give me the result as shown in the data table above."

this is simply not true - please try it and update your question accordingly.

I am speculating here: I think you are trying to use "Distinct" but also output the other fields. If you run:

```
select distinct Field1, Field2, Field3 ...
```

Then your output will be "one row per distinct *combination*" of the 3 fields.

Try GROUP BY instead - this will let you select the Max, Min, Sum of other fields while still yielding "one row per unique combined values" for fields included in GROUP BY

example below uses your table to return one row per LOOKUP_VALUE and then the max and min of the remaining fields and the count of total records using your data:

```
select 
     LOOKUP_VALUE, min( LOOKUPS_CODE) LOOKUPS_CODE_min, max( LOOKUPS_CODE) LOOKUPS_CODE_max, min( LOOKUPS_ID) LOOKUPS_ID_min, max( LOOKUPS_ID) LOOKUPS_ID_max, Count(*) Record_Count 
From TableA
Group by LOOKUP_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to select only 1 row of 5% and 1 row of 2%

This will get the lowest value `lookups_code` for each `lookup_value`:

```
SELECT lookup_value,
       lookups_code
FROM   (
  SELECT lookup_value,
         lookups_code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY lookup_value ORDER BY lookups_code ) AS rn
  FROM   TableA
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

You could also use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT   lookup_value,
         MIN( lookups_code ) AS lookups_code
FROM     TableA
GROUP BY lookup_value
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the MIN() function

I believe this works for your desired output, but am currently not able to test it.

```
SELECT Lookup_Value, MIN(LOOKUPS_CODE) 
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Lookup_Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a total shot in the dark on this one, but because of the way you have named your fields it implies you are attempting to mimic the `vlookup` function within Microsoft Excel.  If this is the case, the behavior when there are multiple matches is to pick the first match.  As arbitrary as that sounds, it's the way it works.

If this is what you want, AND the first value is not necessarily the lowest (or highest, or best looking, or whatever), then the row_number aggregate function would probably suit your needs.

I give you a caveat that my ordering criteria is based on the database row number, which could conceivably be different than what you think.  If, however, you insert them into a clean table (with a reset high water mark), then I think it's a pretty safe bet it will behave the way you want.  If not, then you are better off including a field explicitly to tell it what order you want the choice to occur.

```
with cte as (
  select
    vlookup_value,
    vlookups_code,
    row_number() over (partition by vlookup_value order by rownum) as rn
  from
    TableA
)
select
  vlookup_value, vlookups_code
from cte
where rn = 1
```